# Would it be good if we combine all these [home, questions, unanswered] question page?

Tags: feature-request, design

Would it be good if we combine all these 3 question pages together?

Currently, we have:

---

**Home page [default]**

*this page has 'custom tab' depend on each stack site*

all of default tab

- featured [this one also has in Question Page]
- hot
- week
- month

---

**Question page**

- newest
- featured [this one also has in Home Page]
- frequent
- votes
- active [this one also has in Home Page of meta stackexchange]
- unanswered [this unanswered also has different linked than Unanswered Page => https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered]

---

**Unanswered Page** [this page linked => https://meta.stackexchange.com/unanswered]

- my tags
- newest
- votes
- unanswered

---

So, I just thought, is it good to combine all these page (or just Question and Unanswered page)? We might have some condition field [ex. a checkbox to show only unanswered] to support all these pages.

Comment: @animuson I didn't know you could do that - close as 3 separate targets.